# RestAssured + Java - how can I save to string or to file the Request that sent to the server?

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured, extentreports

Using intellij, Java and restassured:

I am sending the request as needed and I added this to my code:

```
    public static Response PostInstinctQuery() throws IOException, ParseException {
    PrintStream fileOutPutStream = new PrintStream(new File("request_log.txt"));
            config = config().logConfig(new LogConfig().defaultStream(fileOutPutStream));
            RestAssured.baseURI = BASEURI;
            RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
            //Headers
            request.header("Key",key);
          
            request.body(getJson());
            request.log().all();
            Response response = request.post(PATH);
            return response;
}
```

That is save the request in "request_log.txt" file.
so what is the problem ? the file shows the same request over and over.
If I use TestNG diff data then I would expect that the file will contain all the diff request.

And I really want the request to be able to save in a String variable for assert / report purposes also.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to compare different requests - why do you want to go the extra step by comparing files? you can do all that in memory. Prepare the expected result and compare to actual one. Thats how it should be done

Comment: No No No, I want to log the request that sent, I want to assert on it, store it as variable, log it to extent report, And so on....
I am not comparing requests, I am sending multiple requests at once (Load testing) and I need that the request will be equal to the relevant test..

Comment: Ok understood - so the issue is that your logs are always empty? In that case you need to provide more code how you get those reuqest data

Comment: I update the code,
file is not empty, when I run the request multiple times with multi thread or with test ng poolthread the request is written the right number as the pool thread but with same data over and over although test knows how to inject different data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `RequestLoggingFilter` to config one time, no need `log().all()`.

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("request_log.txt");
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(file, true);
RestAssured.filters(RequestLoggingFilter.logRequestTo(stream));
```

Comment: Any way to save the request in a string variable ?
cause in stream it's an issue

Comment: So you want one string var for all info and work under multi thread? No I don’t thing this works

Comment: Yes, per thread I need the relevant request, now it prints all the requests together, I want to split it, request per thread

Comment: Just use apache jmeter.

Comment: But I am using automation test from java code. All works perfect including load test from code. Just want a way to have request per thread, not all the requests at once (stored)

Comment: but I didn't figure how to get request per thread as string variable